# sent auto reply email form in php

Tags: php, html, forms, email, replay

this my php code :

```
<?php
$to = 'makingmoney497@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New EMail From Your web site:MakeMoneyCorner.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = <<<EMAIL

from $name
his email is:$email
EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if($_POST){
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $header, $feedback)
   $feedback = 'your information has been successfully Send it';

}

if ($mail->send()){ 
 $autoemail = new PHPMailer(); 
 $autoemail->From = "makingmoney497@gmail.com"; 
 $autoemail->FromName = "makingmoneycorner.com"; 
 $autoemail->AddAddress($mail->From, $mail->FromName); 
 $autoemail->Subject = "This Is Your Book About Making Money"; 
 $autoemail->Body = "you can download here :";
 $autoemail->Send(); 
 }  

 ?>
```

** // the form work great, i can recieve emails that visitors are sending, but the reply doesn't work
why  ?

img of the problem :http://www.gulfup.com/?e4Nb5X

Comment: Missing `;` on line 17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** If your `mail()` is working, use that function instead of `PHPMailer()` because my previous code should have delivered both.

```
$to = 'makingmoney497@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New EMail From Your web site:MakeMoneyCorner.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
// Your message is set up strangely, try this:
$message = "
From: ".ucwords($name)."
Sent by: $email";
// Your header needs the words "From: " in it
$header = "From: $email";

if($_POST){
    // You are saying if the mail to you succeeds, continue on.
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        // Your browser message to them
        $feedback = 'your information has been successfully Send it';
        if(filter_vars($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $headerRep  = "From: makingmoneycorner.com <makingmoney497@gmail.com>";
            $subjectRep =   "This Is Your Book About Making Money";
            $messageRep =   "you can download here :";
            mail($email, $subjectRep, $messageRep, $headerRep);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn'y work i didn't recieve any replay msg.
can you tell me onther code to use it to send autoumatic replay
thnk you :)

Comment: Are these address correct? `$autoemail->AddAddress($email, $name);` where you want it to reply?

Comment: Also, what you are sending is pretty simple, why not sanitize the reply email address and send the auto-reply using the `mail()` like you do for yours instead of the `PHPMailer()`??

Comment: i didn't understand what u say ; all i need is a code, that when a visitor put his email and name get autoumatic replay of a link ; how should i do that plz,

Comment: i am sorry to say that, but it doesn't work, i get the mesage from the visitor , but i don't get the visitor don't get the replay

Comment: That error you are getting is because you are missing a semi-colon: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $header, $feedback);`

Comment: That will fix that error, but there is no guarantee it will send...I still don't know where this `$mail->send()` is coming from...

Answer (score 0):

```
this th hole code that i use :

'
<?php


$to = 'makingmoney497@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New EMail From Your web site:MakeMoneyCorner.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = <<<EMAIL

from $name
his email is:$email
EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if($_POST){
    // You are saying if the mail to you succeeds, continue on.
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header, $feedback)) {
        // Your browser message to them
        $feedback = 'your information has been successfully Send it';
        if(filter_vars($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $headerRep  = "From: makingmoneycorner.com <makingmoney497@gmail.com>";
            $subjectRep =   "This Is Your Book About Making Money";
            $messageRep =   "you can download here :";
            mail($email, $subjectRep, $messageRep, $headerRep);
        }
    }
}






?>'






<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />

<title>make money online</title>
</head>
    <div id="wrap">    

    <br> .</br>

            <form action="?" method="post" >

               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                  </li>

                  <li>
                     <label for="email">Your  Email:</label>
                     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
                  </li>
               </ul>

            </form>




  <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback ?></p> 
       <div id="hurry">
           <input type="image" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/hurry.png';?>" /> 
       </div><!--end hurry-->
    </div> <!--END WRAP-->

   </body>


</html>

'
```

Comment: Ok try my revision now.